# Error occurs when calculating hex numbers

Tags: java, netbeans-7, hex

When I calculating (1 3 +) I get the correct answer.But when I calculate statement like (A 1 +) I get the wrong answer.

In this question I try to evaluate hexadecimal statements like (5 7 + 7 * 8 + ~).

Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack;


/**
 *
 * @author Dilini
 */
public class Acadox {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


    public static boolean isOperator(String c)
    {
        return ( "+".equals(c) || "-".equals(c) || "&".equals(c) || "|".equals(c) || "~".equals(c) || "X".equals(c));
    }



   /* public String convert(String str)
    {
          char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
          StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
          for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
          {
            strBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
          }
          return strBuffer.toString();
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try
        {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String s[]=read.readLine().split(" ");

            Stack<String> st=new Stack<String>();

            st.push(s[0]);
            int i=1;

            int num1,num2,result=0;

            if(isOperator(s[1]) && !"~".equals(s[1]))
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            else if(!isOperator(s[s.length-1]))
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    if(!isOperator(s[i]))
                    {
                        st.push(s[i]);
                        i++;
                    }  
                    else
                    {


                        if("+".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=num1+num2;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }
                        else if("-".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=num1-num2;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }
                        else if("&".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=num1&num2;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }
                        else if("|".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=num1|num2;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }
                        else if("~".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=~num1;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }
                        else if("X".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(), 16);

                            result=num1^num2;
                            st.push(""+result);
                        }

                        i++;

                    }



                }
                while(st.size()!=1);

                result=Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                System.out.println(result);
            }




        }
        catch(IOException e)
       {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Please give me a solution for that.

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be reading your input in hexadecimal but outputting your answers in base-10 (decimal)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies when you do

```
st.push(""+result);
```

This code essentially converts a integer into its base-10 number then converts it into a string. Because of your loop mechanics, when this result is re-parsed by Integer.parseString(st.pop(), 16), it is being read incorrectly (as a base-16 integer when its a base-10 integer).

Replace all your st.push() references with this and try again:

```
st.push(Integer.toString(result, 16));
```